# Javascript Deep Comparison

Tags: javascript

Questions about deep comparison of objects have been asked, and I have the solution. But there is a line in the solution that I don't completely understand.

This is the [solution](https://github.com/marijnh/Eloquent-JavaScript/blob/master/code/solutions/04_4_deep_comparison.js), it is a question in [Ch 4 of Eloquent JS](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#exercise_deep_compare) to compare objects. I get all of it except the line:

```
    if (!(prop in a) || !deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop]))
```

It is found toward the bottom. Here is full function:

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;

  if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
      b == null || typeof b != "object")
    return false;

  var propsInA = 0, propsInB = 0;

  for (var prop in a)
    propsInA += 1;

  for (var prop in b) {
    propsInB += 1;
    if (!(prop in a) || !deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop]))
      return false;
  }

  return propsInA == propsInB;
}
```

Is `if (!(prop in a)` comparing the existence of a property in 'b' at that index, or is it comparing values?

Really the same q. about the second half, but I know it's a different answer: what type of comparison is `!deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop])` making (e.g., true or false)? I understand the recursion, but as in my previous question, is this making an 'it exists' comparison, or a comparison of the information in the values?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

> The **in operator** returns `true` if the specified property is in the specified object.

[Also:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> The **for...in statement** iterates over the [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

So to answer your first question, `prop in a` is checking whether `prop`, a field from object `b`, exists in object `a`.

To answer your second question, `deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop])` is checking whether the object `a[prop]` and `b[prop]` are equal including all its children and contents.

Comment: Thank you caffinatedmonky, (and everyone else for the assistance). That's what I thought but wanted to confirm. I appreciate the information on "in".

Comment: @hikinthru Welcome to stackoverflow. Thank's for not making your first post a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator returns true if the object on the right of the expression contains a key with the value of the string on the left of the expression.

Eg: `prop in a` is true if `a` contains a key with the same name as the string value of `prop`.  Eg:

```
var prop = "age";

var obj1 = {
    name: "Dave",
    age: 21,
    record: { ... }
};
var obj2 = {
    name: "John",
    record: { ... }
};

console.log(prop in obj1); // true
console.log(prop in obj2); // false
```

If `prop` was set to `"record"` then `deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop])` recursively compares the *values* in `a.record` and `b.record`.

Answer (score 0):

It's checking for existence. It says: "For each property in B, examine A. If A doesn't have the property, or if the value of the property on A doesn't deeply equal the value of the property on B, return false".

An alternate implementation would avoid the existence check on that line, and instead use `if (typeof A == 'undefined')` at the top of the function to validate the input parameters at the beginning of each round of recursion...at a glance, I think that'd be equivalent, but less efficient. The current implementation avoids the invocation on the undefined property.

Comment: But then, would `a = {x:undefined}` and `b = {y:undefined}` be "deeply equal" or not?

Comment: Good question! Apparently `undefined == undefined` is true (I wasn't sure it would be...could have been treated as indeterminate), so I suppose a and b in your question SHOULD be deeply equal. Nice catch.