# How can we check if pre-filled is not altered by end user?

Tags: json, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 5 and reactive forms.
My requirement is simple:

I have a form which gets pre-populated using an object.
I store object in a userObj and form values later are stored in payload variable.
I want to compare these two objects and want to conclude that form is being changed or not.

Form Controls:

```
firstNameControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  lastNameControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  phoneControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  emailControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
```

Form object:

```
    userForm: FormGroup;

  this.userForm = new FormGroup({
  firstNameControl: this.firstNameControl,
  lastNameControl: this.lastNameControl,
  emailNameControl: this.emailControl,
  phoneControl: this.phoneControl
 });
```

I get form prepopulated using below object:

```
 let userObj = {
            "user":{
                "profile":{
                    "details":
                    {
                        "firstname":'xyz',
                        "lastname":"abc",
                        "phone":"99987777"
                        "email":"email@gmail.com"

                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

So while submitting form I want to check whether userObj and payload is same

```
  let payload = {
                "user":{
                "profile":{
                    "details":
                    {
                        "firstname": this.firstnameControl
                        "lastname": this.lastnameControl
                        "phone": this.phoneControl.value
                        "email": this.emailControl.value

                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

I tried comparing using JSON.stringify but it did not work.

I have more key values and form controls in actual.

Comment: You can compare all 4 keys in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use simple JSON.stringify there. You have to do deep object comparison as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400594/javascript-deep-comparison)

You can use object comparison function for achieve your goal.I have done a example for you.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxsjy5)