# Comparing two object that have nested data and get the keys of different values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I'm attempting to get the keys from an object comparison. If the comparison finds a different object, it should return the key that has to be updated, This is the object:

```
{
  "crm": "",
  "dateReceita": "2023-07-27T03:00:00.000Z",
  "imagens": [
    {
      "extension": "jpeg",
      "url": "https://firebasestorage.jhsCYMi9l0Zgcw1%2F29544f6b-caec-4e42-93ae-3b4f3f9a854a.jpeg?alt=media&token=78e"
    }
  ],
  "laboratorio": "",
  "lotes": [
    {
      "lote": "LOte0",
      "loteQtd": "8"
    },
    {
      "lote": "Lote 2",
      "loteQtd": "2"
    }
  ],
  "nome": "Lotes",
  "produto": "Dem",
  "quantidade": 10,
  "tipo": "Branca",
  "vendida": true
}
```

This is the function I'm runnig:

```
const getNew = (newObj, oldObj) => {
    if (Object.keys(oldObj).length == 0 && Object.keys(newObj).length > 0)
      return newObj

    const diff = {}
    for (const key in oldObj) {
      if (newObj[key] && oldObj[key] != newObj[key]) {
        diff[key] = newObj[key]
      }
    }

    if (Object.keys(diff).length > 0) return diff

    return oldObj
  }
```

Although if I compare that object with itself, it always shows that `imagens` and `lotes` have some different data, even though it does not

Comment: You can't deeply compare objects with `==` or `!=`.   These will compare by reference and produce the behavior you are seeing.   Instead, you will need to recurse (or use a stack-based implementation) to compare values between the two objects with same-named keys.   You might also use some library to do this (lodash has an `_isEqual()` and is popular), or could use the "kludge" of comparing the output of `JSON.stringify()` with `!=`.  However, neither of these last two ways is ideal if you want the key that needs updating.  Also notice that there is a /path/ of keys potentially involved....

Comment: To clarify, using `==` or `===` is not relevant for reference types. You cannot deeply compare object with either. So I'd better say you cannot deeply (or value) compare reference types with JS equality operators.

Answer (score 0):

Its very important in high level languages to understand which types are reference type and which types are value type.
For value types, value is compared for equality, for reference types, the reference (memory address) is compared for equality. The reference is the address in memory. So if two reference types are compared for equality, if they are different instances, they will have a different memory address and they will be different.
In your case you are obtaining `imagens` and `lotes` because an array is a reference type. If those are different array instances, they are not equal according to `==` or `===`.

For that you need a function that compares the values for you as the one below. Libraries do this for you also as mentioned in the comments.

```js
const myObj = {
    "crm": "",
    "dateReceita": "2023-07-27T03:00:00.000Z",
    "imagens": [
      {
        "extension": "jpeg",
        "url": "https://firebasestorage.jhsCYMi9l0Zgcw1%2F29544f6b-caec-4e42-93ae-3b4f3f9a854a.jpeg?alt=media&token=78e"
      }
    ],
    "laboratorio": "",
    "lotes": [
      {
        "lote": "LOte0",
        "loteQtd": "8"
      },
      {
        "lote": "Lote 2",
        "loteQtd": "2"
      }
    ],
    "nome": "Lotes",
    "produto": "Dem",
    "quantidade": 10,
    "tipo": "Branca",
    "vendida": true
  }

  const myObj2 = {
    "crm": "",
    "dateReceita": "2023-07-27T03:00:00.000Z",
    "imagens": [
      {
        "extension": "jpeg",
        "url": "https://firebasestorage.jhsCYMi9l0Zgcw1%2F29544f6b-caec-4e42-93ae-3b4f3f9a854a.jpeg?alt=media&token=78e",
        "what":'wat'
      }
    ],
    "laboratorio": "",
    "lotes": [
      {
        "lote": "LOte0",
        "loteQtd": "8"
      },
      {
        "lote": "Lote 2",
        "loteQtd": "2"
      }
    ],
    "nome": "Lotes",
    "produto": "Dem",
    "quantidade": 10,
    "tipo": "Branca",
    "vendida": true
  }

  function isObjArrayValueEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    // Check if both arguments are arrays
    if (!Array.isArray(arr1) || !Array.isArray(arr2)) {
      return false;
    }
  
    // Check if both arrays have the same length
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
      return false;
    }
  
    // Compare each object in the arrays
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
      const obj1 = arr1[i];
      const obj2 = arr2[i];
  
      // Check if both elements are objects
      if (typeof obj1 !== 'object' || typeof obj2 !== 'object' || obj1 === null || obj2 === null) {
        return false;
      }
  
      // Get the keys of each object
      const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
      const keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);
  
      // Check if both objects have the same number of properties
      if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
        return false;
      }
  
      // Compare the values of each property in the objects
      for (const key of keys1) {
        if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  
    // If all comparisons pass, the arrays are equal
    return true;
  }

  const getNew = (newObj, oldObj) => {
    if (Object.keys(oldObj).length == 0 && Object.keys(newObj).length > 0)
      return newObj

    const diff = {}
    for (const key in oldObj) {
      if (newObj[key] && (oldObj[key] !== newObj[key])) {
        if (Array.isArray(newObj[key])) {
            if (!isObjArrayValueEqual(newObj[key], oldObj[key])) {
                diff[key] = newObj[key]        
            }
        } else {
            diff[key] = newObj[key]
        }
        
      }
    }

    if (Object.keys(diff).length > 0) return diff

    return diff
  }

  console.log(getNew(myObj, myObj2))
```

If you have other reference types in your object that are not arrays and are reference types, you would need to use a value compare function (of your own or from a library) to check for value equality.

Answer (score 0):

Lotes and imagens are also objects so the == or != operators won't give you the desired result. You'll need to modify your function to check if the keys hold values that are objects and call it recursively, making your function capable of comparing objects deeply.
Here's an idea to help you out.

```
// create a function to be used for comparing objects
function compareObjects(difference, oldObj, newObj) {
   for (const key of oldObj) {
      if (newObj[key]) {
          // the new object has that key
              if (typeof key == "object" && typeof key == "object") {
          // if they are both objects, call the function again with the keys as arguments
              compareObjects(difference[key], oldObj[key], newObj[key])
          //skip the rest of this iteration
              continue
          }
          // if they keys aren't objects
          if (oldObj[key] != newObj[key]) {
             difference[key] = newObj[key]
          }
       }
    }
}

const getNew = (newObj, oldObj) => {
    if (Object.keys(oldObj).length == 0 && Object.keys(newObj).length > 0)
      return newObj

    const diff = {}
    compareObjects(diff, oldObj, newObj)

    if (Object.keys(diff).length > 0) return diff

    return oldObj
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the flowing code, it can find and print the differences of two objects, including deep differences.

I think you can just make a small change in method diffAsStr, so it returns the keys they way that you need (e.g. perhaps return keys as an array of strings).

```
function deepCompareObjects(obj1, obj2, path = '') {
  const diff = {};
  for (let key in obj1) {
    const currentPath = path ? `${path}.${key}` : key;
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (!obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        diff[currentPath] = [obj1[key], undefined];
      } else if (typeof obj1[key] === 'object' && typeof obj2[key] === 'object') {
        const nestedDiff = deepCompareObjects(obj1[key], obj2[key], currentPath);
        if (Object.keys(nestedDiff).length > 0) {
          Object.assign(diff, nestedDiff);
        }
      } else if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
        diff[currentPath] = [obj1[key], obj2[key]];
      }
    }
  }
  for (let key in obj2) {
    const currentPath = path ? `${path}.${key}` : key;
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key) && !obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      diff[currentPath] = [undefined, obj2[key]];
    }
  }
  return diff
}

function diffAsStr(differences: any): string {
  let res = ""
  for (let key in differences) {
    if (res != '') res += ', '
    res += `${key}: ${differences[key][0]} -> ${differences[key][1]}`
  }
  return res
}

const obj1 = {no: '1', data: {name:'a'}, size: 1}
const obj2 = {no: '2', data: {name:'b'}, size: 2}

const differences = deepCompareObjects(obj1, obj2);
console.log(diffAsStr(differences)) // prints: no: 1 -> 2, data.name: a -> b, size: 1 -> 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function findUpdatedKeys(originalObj, updatedObj) {
  const updatedKeys = {};

    for (const key in originalObj) {
      if (originalObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (!updatedObj.hasOwnProperty(key) || originalObj[key] !== updatedObj[key]) {
          updatedKeys[key] = updatedObj[key];
        }
      }
    }

    return updatedKeys;
}
```

```js
const originalObject = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 30,
  email: 'john@example.com',
};

const updatedObject = {
  name: 'Jane Doe',
  age: 31,
  email: 'jane@example.com',
};

const updatedKeys = findUpdatedKeys(originalObject, updatedObject);
console.log(updatedKeys);
```

Comment: you made the same logic as I posted and this is not the solution.